# PHP. How does user defined compare function work?

Tags: php, compare

Example:

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($a, "cmp");

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
?>
```

Result

```
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
3: 5
4: 6
```

in the user defined compare function '`cmd`', it has two arguments, `$a` & `$b`.

What do the first and second argument represent? Are they `array[x]` and `array[x+1]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are just two of the elements from the array being sorted, not necessarily neighbours.  `usort` performs some sort algorithm (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms), which involves comparing various pairs of elements to determine their order.  It uses your callback function to determine this.

Comment: As a general note: PHP uses a quicksort algorithm

Comment: don't get it. "They are just two of the elements from the array being sorted".  Say in this case, $a is which element, $b is which?

Comment: @MarkBaker: I assumed it did, but couldn't prove it.  Is that documented anywhere, or is that gleaned from looking at the source?

Comment: @gilzero: It could be any pair, in general.  Take a look at how e.g. the [quicksort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) or the [bubblesort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubblesort) work; they all involve performing comparisons on arbitrary pairs of elements.

Comment: @MarkBaker @Oli PHP has a generic hashtable sorting function `zend_hash_sort` (http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_hash.c#1421), but in practice it is always provided with a `zend_qsort` (http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_qsort.c#56) sorting function (e.g. http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/ext/standard/array.c#536). So yeah, PHP uses quicksort :)

Comment: @Oli - I know it's somewhere in the docs on php.net, but can't recall exactly where... but you'll find the source in zend_hash_sort in Zend\zend_hash.c but it uses Zend/zend_qsort.c ... looks like while I was searching the source it already got answered